# How can I make the c++ chrono steady_clock stop returning system_clock times?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, system-clock, c2664

I was writing a class that dealt with optional time constraints for certain methods, and so it takes classes from the `std::chrono` namespace to specify how to define the times. I was trying to test this method that is supposed to expire once it passes a given `time_point`:

```
template <typename Clock, typename Rep, typename Per>
class Foo
{
public:
    bool bar(const std::chrono::time_point<Clock, std::chrono::duration<Rep, Per>>&);
};
```

After my first failed attempt at calling the method, I realized I should use `std::chrono::time_point_cast`. The method call looks like:

```
Foo<std::chrono::steady_clock, long long, std::milli> obj;
obj.bar(std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::duration<long long, std::milli>(std::chrono::steady_clock::now()));
```

I get this IntelliSense error:

```
IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::milli>>" to "const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long, std::milli>>" exists
```

When I try to compile it, I get:

```
error C2664: 'Foo<Clock,Rep,Per>::bar' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::chrono::time_point<_Clock,_Duration>' to 'const std::chrono::time_point<_Clock,_Duration> &'
```

I have no idea why, but the `time_point` returned by `steady_clock` is a time_point that uses `system_clock` instead. I even specifically set the `time_point_cast` to use `steady_clock`, and it still always gives me `system_clock`. This is really annoying, considering that now the class is completely unusable when `steady_clock` is used in place of `system_clock`. If `steady_clock` and `system_clock` are virtually the same thing, is there some way I am missing to convert times between the two?

Edit: I am using Visual Studio Professional 2012. Also, it appears `steady_clock` derives from `system_clock`, although that doesn't seem to help at the moment.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: See this question and its answers regarding Microsoft's possibly buggy implementation of `<chrono>` clocks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488075/vs11-is-steady-clock-steady. I believe the implementation should be fixed in an upcoming version of VS.

Comment: No current versions of Visual Studio have a working `<chrono>` implementation. You'll basically have to write your own clock class using winapi functions like `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Except for you, Microsoft.